# Call same function in jquery after modal shows up

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm using bootstrap modals to show the contents in my divs when a text is clicked (surrounded by `<span>`).

I call it by `$(#div_to_show").modal()` whenever you click the text inside a span tag. `modal()` is part of the bootstrap modal javascript.

My span uses the class `someClass`. I use

```
function update() 
{
    ('.someClass').click(function() {
        var atr = $(this).attr("atr");

        $.get("../Folder/getFile?atr="atr, function(data) {
            json=JSON.parse(data);

            if(typeof(json.error) == "undefined") {
                var foobar = json.foo.replace(/_/g, '"');
                bar("#div_to_show", foobar);
                $("#div_to_show").modal();
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
}
```

I could add `update();` after `$(#div_to_show").modal();` but that causes it to go in an infinite loop even though the modal showed up and the span is not being clicked.

My question is how can I call the function `update()` whenever you click the text which is wrapped around span?

Comment: Why would you want to call this update function, it doesn't do anything extra?

Comment: It does. I just left most of the code out to keep it simple and I can't really show it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So why not put that extra code in a different method that doesn't affect the modal?

Comment: Thanks, trying to make work like that right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.someClass').on('click', function() {
    update();
});

function update()
{
    $("#div_to_show").modal();
}
```

Comment: Never mind there was a typo. However, the modal is still not working on click. It opens up when the page loads.

Comment: Try $('.someClass').off (); before onclick

Comment: That didn't do anything. If it helps, `update()` is also being called from other functions on the page which is why it appears on page load. Also, in my original code in op, a different modal shows up depending on an attribute in the span tag. I guess I made the code too simple. I'm sorry, I'll update it.

Comment: Is return false important for the function? If not try removing it.

Comment: Yes, without it the data doesn't show in the modal.